# My Shiny App works locally but not on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I built a simple shiny app. It works fine locally but gives me an error when I load it to shinyapps.io.

Here is the error message:

*An error has occurred!
An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.*

Here is the output from the logs.

```
> rsconnect::showLogs(appName="vaccines-by-country",streaming=TRUE) 
2021-05-25T11:12:17.576509+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'tibble':
        2021-05-25T11:12:17.576512+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]:   method     from  
2021-05-25T11:12:17.679447+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]:     filter, lag
2021-05-25T11:12:17.576512+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]:   format.tbl pillar
2021-05-25T11:12:17.679448+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:12:17.576512+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]:   print.tbl  pillar
2021-05-25T11:12:17.679812+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: The following objects are masked from â€˜package:baseâ€™:
        2021-05-25T11:12:17.678697+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:12:17.679814+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:12:17.678700+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: Attaching package: â€˜dplyrâ€™
2021-05-25T11:12:17.679447+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:12:17.678701+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:12:17.679446+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: The following objects are masked from â€˜package:statsâ€™:
        2021-05-25T11:12:17.679812+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:12:17.679813+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2021-05-25T11:12:17.872130+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]:   88: <Anonymous>
        2021-05-25T11:12:17.863510+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: error reading from the connection
2021-05-25T11:15:32.272140+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: Running on host: 16ba9f6b9d17
2021-05-25T11:15:32.276813+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: R version: 4.0.2
2021-05-25T11:15:32.276812+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2021-05-25T11:15:32.276832+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: shiny version: 1.5.0
2021-05-25T11:15:32.276800+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: Server version: 1.8.6.1
2021-05-25T11:15:32.276876+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: rmarkdown version: (none)
2021-05-25T11:15:32.276911+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: knitr version: (none)
2021-05-25T11:15:32.276918+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: jsonlite version: 1.7.1
2021-05-25T11:15:32.276942+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: htmltools version: 0.5.1.1
2021-05-25T11:15:32.277087+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.11
2021-05-25T11:15:32.276869+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: httpuv version: 1.5.5
2021-05-25T11:15:32.434697+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2021-05-25T11:15:32.276919+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2021-05-25T11:15:32.437887+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:15:32.437888+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: Starting R with process ID: '26'
2021-05-25T11:15:32.462208+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:46118
2021-05-25T11:15:32.462207+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:15:43.997554+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'tibble':
        2021-05-25T11:15:43.997556+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]:   method     from  
2021-05-25T11:15:43.997556+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]:   format.tbl pillar
2021-05-25T11:15:43.997557+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]:   print.tbl  pillar
2021-05-25T11:15:44.099489+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:15:44.099492+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: Attaching package: â€˜dplyrâ€™
2021-05-25T11:15:44.099492+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:15:44.100245+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: The following objects are masked from â€˜package:statsâ€™:
        2021-05-25T11:15:44.100245+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:15:44.100246+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:15:44.100246+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]:     filter, lag
2021-05-25T11:15:44.100607+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: The following objects are masked from â€˜package:baseâ€™:
        2021-05-25T11:15:44.100608+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:15:44.100609+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2021-05-25T11:15:44.100609+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: 
        2021-05-25T11:15:44.285726+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]: Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: error reading from the connection
2021-05-25T11:15:44.293913+00:00 shinyapps[4164097]:   88: <Anonymous>
```

Warning: Error in Anonymous: error reading from the connection

Here is my ui.R code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
df <- read_csv("country_vaccinations.csv.zip")
countries <- df %>% distinct(country)

fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Covid Vaccines by Country by Maria Freydlin"),
        h4("Instructions:"),
        h5("Please select a country from the dropdown list below to view the timeline of total vaccines administered within the last few months."),
        a(href="https://github.com/mariafreydlin/shinyapp/tree/master", 'Link to UI and Server code files'),
        titlePanel("Vaccine Timeline by Country"),   
        
        sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput( "country", "Country:", choices=countries),
                        hr()
                        
                ),
                mainPanel(
                        plotOutput("vaccinePlot")
                )
        )
)
```

And here is my server.R code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
df <- read_csv("country_vaccinations.csv.zip")

function(input, output){
        df_total <- reactive({
                df %>%
                        filter(country==input$country)%>%
                        group_by(date) %>%
                        summarise(total = sum(total_vaccinations, na.rm = T))
        })
        
        output$vaccinePlot <- renderPlot({
                ggplot(df_total(), aes(date, total)) + geom_line() +theme_bw()
        })
}
```

The csv.zip file is located in the same folder as ui.R and server.R.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: Also the csv.zip file is included when I load everything to shinyapps, I made sure.

Comment: And if you clear all variables from the workspace (e.g. using `rm(ls = list())`) does it still work locally?

Comment: What if you unzip it and change you code to read a .csv instead of a .zip?

Comment: Yes! Unzipping prior to reading .csv solved the issue for me! Thank you Eric!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Eric in the comments I unzipped the csv.zip file and read .csv instead. This solved the issue!

```
file = unzip("country_vaccinations.csv.zip")
df <- read_csv(file)
```

Thank you!